# Child Theme Variables

Tags: child-theme, variables

In my theme, I used this:

```
<div id="brickwall" data-brickinvert="<?php echo brickAlign(); ?>">
```

I put the code into functions.php:

```
function brickAlign() {
    $a = "true";
    return $a;
}
```

Now in the child theme, I would like to change $a to false.

Then in child theme my html would look like:

```
<div id="brickwall" data-brickinvert="false">
```

I want to keep the function name the same, so that I won't have to copy all the files to change one variable.  But of course I cannot put function with same name in child.

I tried using global, but it caused errors.  I also tried to do filters but my bleeping computer was having none of that either.  The reason is so I can pass a variable into my Masonry jQuery script using the html data attribute, for aligning my bricks to top or to bottom, depending on which theme I'm in, parent or child.  Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your function filterable:

```
function brickAlign() {
    $a = "true";
    return apply_filters( 'brick_align', $a );
}
```

Then, in your child Theme, add a filter callback:

```
function child_theme_filter_brick_align( $a ) {
    return 'false';
}
add_filter( 'brick_align', 'child_theme_filter_brick_align' );
```

Alternately, you could pass a parameter to your function:

```
function brickAlign( $value = 'true' ) {
    // Note: you should add some error-checking here
    $a = $value;
    return $a;
}
```

Then, in your Child Theme, call the function like so:

```
<?php brickAlign( 'false' ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Chip, your first solution worked! So does the other one posted below.

Comment: In probably an hour and a half of googling, this is the first explanation of how this works that I've come across that makes sense. Thank you from three years in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the function in your main theme pluggable like this:

```
if ( !function_exists('brickAlign') ) {
    function brickAlign() {
        $a = "true";
        return $a;
    }
}
```

That way you can make a custom `brickAlign()` function in your child theme that overrides the parent theme function:

```
function brickAlign() {
    $a = "false";
    return $a;
}
```

Comment: This is enlightening.  I should probably do this to all of my functions?  I think I will! :)

Comment: I prefer filters to pluggable functions, as they are easier to maintain. With Pluggable functions, if you make changes/tweaks to the original functions, you have to propagate those changes manually to the Child Theme - when all you want to do in the Child Theme is change one, minor value (like 'true' to 'false').

Comment: That makes sense.  I never would have figured out to put the filter inside the function though.  The 'if not' answer is very intuitive & easier to remember later, but I see your point about maintainability.